# Is the galsim boost dependency really needed?

Tags: boost, galsim

I see that there is a `noboost` branch in the `GalSim` repository, but is there any reason why Boost is still being used in the main line?  Would be very useful if you'd just get rid of the unnecessary and painful dependency.  I'd be happy to do some work for this if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The noboost branch is our effort to get rid of the boost dependency.  It currently still uses boost too, but that's where we're doing the work to remove boost.  It will eventually become GalSim v2.0 once that effort is complete.  (Hopefully by the end of 2017.)